# Can types in standard library be over-aligned?

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

I am trying to figure out if any type/class/struct/etc in C++ standard library (for example std::vector or std::thread) in theory could be over-aligned (alignof(T) > alignof(max_align_t)). It is not clear for me from specification. Is it required that every type from standard library have fundamental alignment requirement?

Comment: Obviously not, or else `std::pair<int, OverAlignedType>` could not possibly work. Or `optional<OverAlignedType>`. Or similar such things.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?  In other words, what depends on the answer to this question?

Comment: If type is over-aligned than I can't use plain malloc/new for it.

Comment: @Barricadenick: No, you *may not* be able to, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it required that every type from standard library have fundamental alignment requirement?

There is no such requirement.

> Can types in standard library be over-aligned?

Yes. Here is an example that passes on a particular system for example. It demonstrates an overaligned type that is instance of a standard library template:

```
constexpr std::size_t overaligned = alignof(std::max_align_t) * 2;
struct alignas(overaligned) test {};
static_assert(alignof(std::array<test, 1>) > alignof(std::max_align_t));
```

> If type is over-aligned than I can't use plain malloc/new for it.

You can use `new` on over aligned types since C++17 if extended alignment is supported in the first place. In C++11, whether over aligned new is supported is implementation defined even if the implementation does support over aligned types.